# Mozilla Observatory can’t parse my CSP header

Tags: content-security-policy

Mozilla Observatory used to rate my managed WP site as A+, but currently returns it at B, with 25 points deducted as “Content Security Policy (CSP) header cannot be parsed successfully.” The CSP still gets an A+ at <securityheaders.com>.

My CSP’s script-src directive includes a strict-dynamic value with no nonce or hash values as I have yet to read up properly how to generate those. Could that be the issue, as it maybe stops all script use?